# create challenges to do, in doing or for doing?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

Are they all correct and idiomatic?

> 1. The situation has created financial challenges for the school **to
>    retain** qualified teachers.

> 2. The situation has created financial challenges for the school **for
>    retaining** qualified teachers.

> 3. The situation has created financial challenges for the school **in
>    retaining** qualified teachers.

Comment: All okay, but I would always avoid repeating the preposition like for-for:  "**for** the school **for** retaining."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I use "difficulties" instead of 'challenges' in that sentence, can I still use "to retain". I usually see "create difficulties in doing something" and not 'create difficulties to do something".

Comment: Challenges, difficulties, no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure any are the right choice. Note, this noun use of "challenge" doesn't necessarily follow the same patterns that a verb version does. I might "challenge you *to* fight," I might be "challenged *in* physical mobility," or even "challenged *at* swimming."

But the real verb here is "created," so our prepositions ultimately relate to that. I might actually go with "... created financial challenges for the school **with regard to** retaining qualified teachers." Except that that sounds a bit stuffy, so I might reword to a more direct and active structure: "... has made it challenging for the school **to** retain qualified teachers." (In this case it would definitely be *to*.)

If I had to choose from the original choices, I would choose "created challenges ... *in* retaining."